# change the domain when a value exceeds the maximum and minimum value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I appreciate the attention provided. I have several lines that represent a line chart. currently the domain is between 0 and 100.

```
 var y = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, 100])
```

but in some specific times I would like this domain to change according to the new data entered.

```
        // Add new values
        var count_for=0;
        for (var name in groups) {
            count_for++;
            var group = groups[name]
            if(count<=15 || count>=35){
              group.data.push(20 + Math.random() * 100)
            }
            if(count>15 && count<20){
               group.data.push(124+count_for)
            }
            if(count>=20 && count<25){
               group.data.push(200+count_for)
            }
            if(count>=25 && count<35){
               group.data.push(-8-count_for)
            }

            group.path.attr('d', line)
        }
        count++;
```

and the data that has been drawn would like them to be adjusted according to the new domain. how can I do it?

http://plnkr.co/edit/pOvnRRN3ecbnvLNWOt1h?p=preview

Comment: Once new data is pushed, you need to update the domain of y by `y.domain(d3.extent(group.data))`. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Gunner I would think so, how can I make it look like an animation, or something more fluid to show the change in all lines? comments as a response to mark you.

Comment: I was trying to fix the transitions but was not able to. Need to check on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time a new data is pushed, the domains need to be recalculated. To update the domain of y, you can use `y.domain(d3.extent(group.data))`.

Comment: Does the domain change per line, or is it general for all lines?

Comment: Domain changes per line, unless you already know what the new domains will be. In that case, you could make it general for all lines.

Comment: how can do it?? can you use my plunk please..?

Comment: Updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/o1iqIrYgoKPy6v3kjbw8?p=info. Added comments on how to do it per line and update domain in general.

Comment: Can you help me with a similar question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46803382/change-the-domain-of-my-line-chart-at-runtime