# change the domain of my line chart at runtime

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In my code I am loading a JSON of more than 900 data. these data represent the data emitted by some machines. I'm drawing a line chart, the keys in this JSON represent the name of the machines.

This is the structure of my JSON:

`{"AF3":3605.1496928113393,"AF4":-6000.4375230516,"F3":1700.3827875419374,"F4":4822.544985821321,"F7":4903.330735023786,"F8":824.4048714773611,"FC5":3259.4071092472655,"FC6":4248.067359141752,"O1":3714.5106599153364,"O2":697.2904723891061,"P7":522.7300768483767,"P8":4050.79490288753,"T7":2939.896657485737,"T8":9.551935316881588}`

each line represents each machine and I put a space to see each machine separately. I am currently reading the data with the help of an counter called `cont`. all the data in the JSON is between `0` to `5000`. But I have modified some objects of the JSON to achieve change the domain and then the new domain in general for all the lines must be equal to the change.

for example on line 106 of the JSON to `"AF3":7000`. (in this case the domain should be [0-7000] for all the lines)

in the line 300, `"AF4": - 1000`.(in this case the domain should be [-1000,7000] for all the lines)

I have modified some data on purpose to achieve this change.  I would like all lines to be updated to this new domain, if possible with an animation.

How can I do it?

this is my code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/KVVyOYZ4CVjxeei7pd9H?p=preview

Comment: I have forked the plunker and added code to update domain. Let me know if this is what you were looking for. http://plnkr.co/edit/0MuqjRwlCCxp0B3zwXly?p=preview

Comment: @Gunner @Gunner thanks for your answer. friend I need this to be faster, so I put the duration to 10. something strange happens, when `cont` is 106 it should be displayed the change in all the lines because the maximum value is `7000` and at that moment you do not see any change in the lines.at that moment I do not see the lines being rescaled. why? is there any way to display the current domain console? for example `0-5000`, `0-7000`,` -1000,7000` according to the case  https://i.imgur.com/S5OrnVY.jpg

Comment: @Gunner sorry, I think it was a visual error on my part, I just tried with 15000 instead of 7000 and you see a change. (to be sure that's why I want to show the domain) the answer to my question is that it's OK, right? , perhaps it was an error of perception of mine. I am interested in trying to show these lines and walk the data as fast as possible. if `duration` gives you the value of 1, why is the graph trimmed? https://i.imgur.com/zJqN67C.jpg

Comment: So I'm guessing domain gets updated now? I dont see the trimmed graph. Can you replicate it in this plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/0MuqjRwlCCxp0B3zwXly?p=preview

Comment: @Gunner change value of `duration` to 1

Comment: @Gunner is there a way to show the values of the domain, ie the maximum and minimum value? for example: [0,7000]

Comment: Check this plunk and see if this works. http://plnkr.co/edit/AHWVM3HT7TDAiINFRlN9?p=preview

Comment: Duration 1 is too less for the data to get manipulated. That's the reason the graph looks trimmed.

Comment: @Gunner I need mark you answer. please,can you explain me "Duration 1 is too less for the data to get manipulated. That's the reason the graph looks trimmed" I dont understand you.

Comment: That was just a guess. So from what I think, data needs to be manipulated ( 14 arrays, push and shift operation to the array) all within a 1ms, which may not be enough. Unfortunately I don't have any resource to back this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update domain across all line charts, we need to recalculate the domain before new data gets pushed in.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/AHWVM3HT7TDAiINFRlN9?p=preview

```
var newDomain = d3.extent(ids.map(function(d) {
  return aData[cont][d]
}));
var oldDomain = y.domain()
newDomain[0] = newDomain[0] < oldDomain[0] ? newDomain[0] : oldDomain[0]
newDomain[1] = newDomain[1] > oldDomain[1] ? newDomain[1] : oldDomain[1]
y.domain(newDomain)
domain.text(y.domain())
```

With respect to graph getting trimmed, data needs to be manipulated ( In your case, 14 arrays, push and shift operation to the array and D3 transition) all within a 1ms, which may not be enough. Unfortunately I don't have any resource to back this up. In case anyone can edit this answer to provide proof, please feel free.

Comment: there is no doubt that you are a genius, your answers satisfy me and I learn new things., can you help me please with this question?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46823073/how-can-i-make-to-display-my-data-more-quickly-on-my-chart